# Attribute creation from one single table

Tags: microstrategy

I have one table.

I have to make attributes only from the fields on that table.

I have to use these attributes on one report.

I wanted to ask that all the attributes I have made are keys. Is this fine? If not, how do I resolve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Keys are like primary, foreign keys in RDBMS. They define the joins
So long as you do not have other tables involved in the design, this is fine.

Ideally attributes are made only for dimensions 
e.g
you could make attribute called Issue with forms(Issue id, Issue desc, Issue date) with Issue id as the ID form that drives the join with the other tables

Answer (score 0):

All attributes should not be keys. Every key denotes that the tool is interpreting them as primary keys. Set proper relationship (parent-child) between the attributes and you will see keys only for the child attribute(s).